-48V to +5V using LT1072HV, output is 5.5V instead of 5V
I want to convert -48V DC fromtelecom power to +5V DC, I'm considering this schematic:

Sometimes rectifier output of telecom is -54 DC,hence I'm considering this schematic for -40V to -60V input.
I've calculated R1 and R2 using this formula:
R1= R2*(Vout-Vbe)/Vref
where, Vout = 5, Vbe= 0.6, Vref= 1.244
But when I simulated this schematic in LTspice, the output was +5.55V.

But I want it to 4.9V~5.2V. This +5V DC will be used for runnning microcontroller, sensors, and provide boolean output (+5V). How to solve this?
Besides this I want to know how to calculate the value of inductor (L1), for 1A and 1.25A. I went through the datasheet, but that was confusing to me.

What’s the purpose of Q1?

@winny It's given without explanation for the example topology in the datasheet, but I believe it's to level-shift the feedback, as the LT1072 used like this would need the feedback signal to be a voltage relative to the negative rail, not to ground.

@Hearth Interesting solution! Never seen it before.

If you change R1 to 3k3, you should have 4.9 ... V. L should be ~100 uH.

@winny To elaborate on why it's important a little: Without it, you could design this as a 48 V to 53 V boost converter, which would result in a usable 5 V output, but only so long as the input is well regulated. If the input voltage were instead -49 V, you'd get +4 V out, and -50 V would give +3 V out. Likewise, an input of -47 V gives +6 V out, and -46 V in gives +7 V out. Also, the ±30 mV tolerance of the reference voltage would be magnified to a ±1.28 V output tolerance even with a good -48 V in, which is a tolerance of worse than ±25% as far as the 5 V output is concerned.

@winny (I know you, as an experienced EE, might not need this elaboration, but I wanted it to be here somewhere at least, because it's not very obvious what its role is, or how necessary it is!)

@Hearth In this case, I do. :-) The very few negative rails I've worked on, the PMICs had this level-shifting built in so I never had to dig into how to do it externally.

The formula is just an approximation so don't be disappointed in getting +5.55 volts. I mean the BJT base-emitter junction isn't a precise forward volt drop of 0.6 volts <-- it can vary with device selection and, it will vary a little bit with temperature. It's a clever circuit in that the BJT avoids most of the problems in making a 53 volt boosted output from a 48 volt supply by using two resistors (which can be quite a poor regulated output at 5 volts) but, it's not going to be perfect by any means.
It can be improved by using a TL431 and an opto-coupler (like a flyback supply) but, it depends how far you want to go with accuracy and, how much more you can spend on the components.

Can you share any schematic with TL431 and opto-coupler for improvement? It'll be helpfull.

You should research how a flyback controller works using the devices I mentioned. I can't do this work for you then explain how it works then help you implement this because that's the way this will lead. Or, maybe raise a new post to draw other folk into helping you.
